# get two date variable from range of dates

Tags: php, date-range

I Have these range date(m/d/yyyy-m/d/yyyy)

```
8/12/2013-8/19/2013
```

And then I want get two date variable with different formats(yyyy-mm-dd) from that date.

```
$date1 = 2013-8-12
$date2 = 2013-8-19
```

Please helm me out from my problem. thanks

Comment: Use `explode` and `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Comment: Quick - everyone post an identical answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `explode`.

```
$string = explode('-','8/12/2013-8/19/2013');

$date1 = explode('/',$string[0]);
$date2 = explode('/',$string[1]);

$finalDate1 = $date1[2].'-'.$date1[0].'-'.$date1[1];
$finalDate2 = $date2[2].'-'.$date2[0].'-'.$date2[1];
```

**Output :**

```
2013-8-12
2013-8-19
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   $var = explode('-','8/12/2013-8/19/2013');
   $date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($var[0]));
   $date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($var[1]));
```

Comment: neat and short. thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

Used `explode` and `date` functions

```
$date_range = "8/12/2013-8/19/2013";
$dates = explode("-", $date_range);

echo $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dates[0]));
echo $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dates[1]));
```

#### Output

```
2013-08-12
2013-08-19
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$daterange = "8/12/2013-8/19/2013";
$dates = explode("-", $daterange );

$date1=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[0]));
$date2=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));
```

**Output**

```
$date1 = 2013-8-12
$date2 = 2013-8-19
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = '8/12/2013-8/19/2013';//the given string
$a = explode('-', $a);// split the string by '-' and store it in array
$date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($a[0]));// returns 2013-08-12
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($a[1]));// returns 2013-08-19
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to `explode` date string  `"8/12/2013-8/19/2013"` , this will return array with two dates.

```
$default = '8/12/2013-8/19/2013';
$date = explode('-',$default);

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date[0]));
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date[1]));
```

**Output**

```
2013-08-12
2013-08-19
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$string = explode('-','8/12/2013-8/19/2013');    
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $string[0]);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $string[1]);

//echo the results :
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d');
echo "<br/>".$date2->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

**Output :**

```
2013-08-12
2013-08-19
```